# Angular Material - Virtual Repeat, increase additional elements to render

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Using [virtual repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat) for a long list with images, this is the code:

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" style="height: 100vh; width:100vw">
    <div class="panel panel-default favorite_listitem" md-virtual-repeat="item in favorites" ng-click="selectAd($event, item)">
        <div class="ad-image" style="background-image: url('{{item.data.thumb}}')"></div>
    </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Virtual repeat works with dynamic reuse of rows visible in the viewport area. I can see that the visible rows are 6 in total. How can i increase them to lets say 15 or 20 so that i have less flicker in my list?

Comment: Do you mean the loaded row size of the virtual repeat or actually the visible container?

Comment: I mean the visible container, yes. I cant find anything in the documentation on how to change it.

Comment: My main problem is the list flicker, i want more visible rows to prevent that as much as possible. I want to render more items than the default number

Comment: is the answer that I posted what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a research it looks that you can change the number of aditional items to render from inside the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/virtualRepeat/virtual-repeater.js).

There you can find the variable  `var NUM_EXTRA = 3;`

By changing this to a larger number you can have more list items rendered.

> /**
>    * Number of additional elements to render above and below the visible area inside
>    * of the virtual repeat container. A higher number results in less flicker when scrolling
>    * very quickly in Safari, but comes with a higher rendering and dirty-checking cost.
>    * @const {number}
>    */
>   var NUM_EXTRA = 3;

Answer (score 0):

Just change the height of the div that's how you get more rows in side the container.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" style="height: 100vh; width:100vw">
    <div class="panel panel-default favorite_listitem" md-virtual-repeat="item in favorites" ng-click="selectAd($event, item)" style="height:10px;">
        <div class="ad-image" style="background-image: url('{{item.data.thumb}}')"></div>
    </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

## EDIT

If you need more for loading items you can see how to change the number of loaded items per "page" from [virtual repeat demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) there you can see the `this.PAGE_SIZE = 50;` changing this you can set the amount of items to be loaded.

Comment: if i set `style="height:10px;"` then my list gets completely destroyed because no image can fit in 10 pixels height. Also the page size you refer to is for the deferred loading, i am using the Vertical Usage example

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? If you wont change the div height? By giving the height to 10px didn't mean that it needs to be 10px. It's just for example

Comment: thanks for your answer mate, it looks that what i was looking for it was in the source code